# The user credentials are need to obtain access token. Please call the non-silent acquireTokenWithResource methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory, adal

I am using ADALiOS into my app for authentication. When user signIn into the app I am getting following error:

**"The argument 'cacheItem.scopes' is invalid. Value:(null)."**      and

**"The user credentials are need to obtain access token. Please call the non-silent acquireTokenWithResource methods"**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This might happen if keychain sharing is disabled.
One of the probable solution is:

Solution:

Step 1:
Xcode > Target > Capabilities > Keychain Sharing -> Switch to ON

Step 2:
add com.microsoft.adalcache into Keychain Group.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i had enable the keychain sharing but i cannot get the refresh token, same error shown, please give any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern for dealing with iOS that involves firstly looking in the ADAL cache for the credentials (the silent version) - if the credentials are not there, then calling the version that pops up the UI for gathering the credentials (the non-silent version)

You can see this in the example app here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/blob/master/Samples/MyTestiOSApp/MyTestiOSApp/BVTestMainViewController.m

Comment: I am following the same pattern. As application launches it checks for Get_Token_Silently, if it get the token from cache it won't show UI and if it didn't get the token I will request token for non silent method. Every time I open the app, it show me UI for login and getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you are using?

Comment: While adding or updating items in cache, it wasn't updating the scopes and when I was getting the items from cache scope was missing. So i just update the scopes while add or update the cache and I got the token silently. Thanks

Comment: @shashank can you give me more information how to do in code. am also having same problem but cant able to solve