# ADAL Cordova Plugin unable to retain token on ios

Tags: cordova-plugins, adal

I'm still a newbie in the mobile app development arena, please forgive me if I did not provide adequate information, probably because my lack of knowledge on its relevance.  I'll edit with more info upon request.

Here's what I'm using to build my app on a Windows 7 64bit environment:

```
AngularJS 1.0
Phonegap Build 6.3.0 (cloud version)
cordova-android 5.2.1 (as shown on Phonegap build)
cordova-ios 4.2.0 (as shown on Phonegap build)
azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova version 0.7.1
```

I'm testing on:

```
Android phone Samsung Galaxy SCH-I545 os version 5.0.1
iPhone 6S Plus os version 9.3.5
```

Everything went well with Android using ADAL plugin 0.7.1.  However on iPhone, it kept going back to the login screen for authentication to our AD FS even though I **already got authenticated** the first time.  I'm suspecting the token did not get stored in cache, that's why acquireTokenAsync kept getting called? I'm still trying to get my hands on a MAC to troubleshoot further.

Then, I updated to ADAL plugin 0.8.0 to see if that might solve my problem, but now Android stopped working and I got this error:

DEVELOPER_AUTHORITY_IS_NOT_VALID_INSTANCE

I debugged through using developer tool on both 0.7.1 and 0.8.0 and I saw no token coming back in acquireTokenAsync method in version 0.8.0.  Switching back to 0.7.1 and Android works again.

Could anyone guide me on what might be causing this problem on my iPhone and Android? Maybe I'm missing additional settings or files?  The way I updated the ADAL plugin was replacing the cordova-plugin-ms-adal folder under plugins and modify my config.xml file to spec="~0.8.0", that should be sufficient right?

*** Update on cordova-android ***
I finally got 0.8.0 working on my android device by turning off **validateAuthority**

```
var context = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority,false);
```

I think it's because I'm using AD FS (found this comment in ADErrorCodes.h under adal-for-objc):

```
    /*! The passed in authority URL does not pass validation, if you're trying to use ADFS directly you must disable authority validation. */
    /*! An error was raised during the process of validating the authorization authority. */
    AD_ERROR_DEVELOPER_AUTHORITY_VALIDATION = 101
```

*** Update on cordova-ios ***
Debugging in Safari developer tool, I don't have tokenCacheItems after the native method got called.

```
bridge.executeNativeMethod('tokenCacheReadItems',[this.authContext.authority, this.authContext.validateAuthority])
.then(function (tokenCacheItems) {
    tokenCacheItems.forEach(function (item) {
        result.push(new TokenCacheItem(item));
    });
    d.resolve(result);
}, function(err) {
    d.reject(err);
});
```

I spent almost a week on this already and I really appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: I was able to debug in Safari on a Mac.  This is the error I'm getting - "The user credentials are need to obtain access token. Please call the non-silent acquireTokenWithResource methods".  Using that info I found a related post but still unable to resolve my problem, yet.  Here's the post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153055/the-user-credentials-are-need-to-obtain-access-token-please-call-the-non-silent

Comment: Helen, one of our engineers responded to your GitHub issue related to this problem here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova/issues/101.

Is there any chance you can run generated Cordova ios platform (<your-cordova-app>/platforms/ios) using XCode? There will be detailed error trace available in XCode debug window after you made acquireTokenAsync call (something related to token cache write error). Check that com.microsoft.adalcache is correctly added to the application access groups.

Comment: what is authority string in createAuthenticationContext() method?